# Long RegEx pattern isn't working as planned

Tags: python-3.x, regex, split

my regex pattern doesn't seem to be working in Python. This column is comma separated from a spreadsheet, between the commas there are Pipes(`|`) that separate things as well. I'm not worried about the pipes, however. I am needing to use the `re.split()` method to split the string by the comma, however, you'll note in the sample that the users input commas into the string in the first item before the first `|` -- hence my reason for using Regex to establish a pattern to look for. However, it's not working properly and can use another set of eyes as a beginner. I've built and run the Regex through [Regex101](https://regex101.com) to help me and the explanation seems correct, but it still does not return the number of matches I expect.

**My regex pattern**:

`".+\s\|\s\d\d\s\|\s\d\d\d\d\s\|\s\d\d\d\d\s\|\s.{2}\d\d\d\d\s\|\s\d+?\.\d+?,"gm`

**My Sample Test String**:

`ICS: Basic Maintenance | 30 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 12000.0,ICS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 30 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -10200.0,ICS: Basic Maintenance | 40 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 9000.0,ICMS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 40 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -7650.0,ICS: Basic Maintenance | 20 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 13500.0,ICS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 20 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -11475.0,ICCMS: Basic Maintenance | 70 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 12000.0,ICCMS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 70 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -10200.0,ITSM: Laptops, Desktops, Computers | 30 | 4400 | IT0000 | 720400.0`

**Number of Matches I expect**: 9 Matches

**Number of Matches I get**: 1 Match - (0-443) : My exported match from [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gNjsl6/1)

````
"
.\s\|\s\d\d\s\|\s\d\d\d\d\s\|\s\d\d\d\d\s\|\s.\d\d\d\d\s\|\s\d\.\d,
"
gm
. matches any character (except for line terminators)
+ matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v  ])
\| matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
\s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v  ])
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
\s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v  ])
\| matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
\s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v  ])
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
\s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v  ])
\| matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
\s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v  ])
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
\s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v  ])
\| matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
\s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v  ])
. matches any character (except for line terminators)
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
\s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v  ])
\| matches the character | literally (case sensitive)
\s matches any whitespace character (equivalent to [\r\n\t\f\v  ])
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
+? matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
\. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
\d matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
, matches the character , literally (case sensitive)
Global pattern flags
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
m modifier: multi line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
0-443   ICS: Basic Maintenance | 30 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 12000.0,ICS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 30 | 5877 ...
Search reference
space
,
.+\s\|\s\d\d\s\|\s\d\d\d\d\s\|\s\d\d\d\d\s\|\s.{2}\d\d\d\d\s\|\s\d+?\.\d+?,
ICS: Basic Maintenance | 30 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 12000.0,ICS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 30 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -10200.0,ICS: Basic Maintenance | 40 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 9000.0,ICMS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 40 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -7650.0,ICS: Basic Maintenance | 20 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 13500.0,ICS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 20 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -11475.0,ICCMS: Basic Maintenance | 70 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 12000.0,ICCMS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 70 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -10200.0,ITSM: Laptops, Desktops, Computers | 30 | 4400 | IT0000 | 720400.0
ICS: Basic Maintenance | 30 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 12000.0,ICS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 30 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -10200.0,ICS: Basic Maintenance | 40 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 9000.0,ICMS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 40 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -7650.0,ICS: Basic Maintenance | 20 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 13500.0,ICS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 20 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -11475.0,ICCMS: Basic Maintenance | 70 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 12000.0,ICCMS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 70 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -10200.0,ITSM: Laptops, Desktops, Computers | 30 | 4400 | IT0000 | 720400.0
ICS: Basic Maintenance | 30 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 12000.0,ICS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 30 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -10200.0,ICS: Basic Maintenance | 40 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 9000.0,ICMS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 40 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -7650.0,ICS: Basic Maintenance | 20 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 13500.0,ICS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 20 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -11475.0,ICCMS: Basic Maintenance | 70 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 12000.0,```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the data and if you don't worry about the pipes, if you want 9 matches you can match all the values using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) instead of spliting and shorted the pattern a bit:

```
\w+:.*?\b\d+(?:\.\d+)(?=,|$)
```

- `\w+:` Match 1+ word chars and `:`
- `.*?` Match as least chars as possible
- `\b\d+(?:\.\d+)` A word boundary, match 1+ digits an an optional decimal part
- `(?=,|$)` Assert either a comma or end of the string at the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EhsT1W/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/vMy2d2)

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

pattern = r"\w+:.*?\b\d+(?:\.\d+)(?=,|$)"
s = "ICS: Basic Maintenance | 30 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 12000.0,ICS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 30 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -10200.0,ICS: Basic Maintenance | 40 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 9000.0,ICMS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 40 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -7650.0,ICS: Basic Maintenance | 20 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 13500.0,ICS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 20 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -11475.0,ICCMS: Basic Maintenance | 70 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 12000.0,ICCMS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 70 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -10200.0,ITSM: Laptops, Desktops, Computers | 30 | 4400 | IT0000 | 720400.0"

pprint(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['ICS: Basic Maintenance | 30 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 12000.0',
 'ICS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 30 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -10200.0',
 'ICS: Basic Maintenance | 40 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 9000.0',
 'ICMS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 40 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -7650.0',
 'ICS: Basic Maintenance | 20 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 13500.0',
 'ICS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 20 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -11475.0',
 'ICCMS: Basic Maintenance | 70 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 12000.0',
 'ICCMS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 70 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -10200.0',
 'ITSM: Laptops, Desktops, Computers | 30 | 4400 | IT0000 | 720400.0']
```

---

If you have to use [re.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split), you can use a capture group to keep the split values and split on the comma.

The full pattern with the pipes in the match:

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

pattern = r"(\w+:[^|]+\|\s\d\d\s\|(?:\s\d{4}\s\|){2}\s.{2}\d{4}\s\|\s-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?),"
s = "ICS: Basic Maintenance | 30 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 12000.0,ICS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 30 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -10200.0,ICS: Basic Maintenance | 40 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 9000.0,ICMS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 40 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -7650.0,ICS: Basic Maintenance | 20 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 13500.0,ICS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 20 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -11475.0,ICCMS: Basic Maintenance | 70 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 12000.0,ICCMS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 70 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -10200.0,ITSM: Laptops, Desktops, Computers | 30 | 4400 | IT0000 | 720400.0"

pprint(list(filter(None, re.split(pattern, s))))
```

Output

```
['ICS: Basic Maintenance | 30 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 12000.0',
 'ICS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 30 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -10200.0',
 'ICS: Basic Maintenance | 40 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 9000.0',
 'ICMS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 40 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -7650.0',
 'ICS: Basic Maintenance | 20 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 13500.0',
 'ICS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 20 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -11475.0',
 'ICCMS: Basic Maintenance | 70 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 12000.0',
 'ICCMS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 70 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -10200.0',
 'ITSM: Laptops, Desktops, Computers | 30 | 4400 | IT0000 | 720400.0']
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/iJmKL4)

Comment: This pattern fails on this [sample](https://regex101.com/r/8zCafx/1) @Thefourthbird

Comment: @mraguda But that is a different data sample. Try `[^,].*?\b\d+(?:\.\d+)(?=,|$)` https://regex101.com/r/LgNKeN/1

Comment: you're right -- removed the colon `:` from the pattern and it worked. TY!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of matching *everything* at the start with a greedy match `.+\s`, do a lazy match `.*?\s`!

I also cleaned up all the duplicated `\d` with a quantity specifier e.g. `{4}`

`.*?\s\|\s\d{2}\s\|\s\d{4}\s\|\s\d{4}\s\|\s.{2}\d{4}\s\|\s-?\d+?\.\d+?` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3yIE8d/2),

which has eight matches:

```
0-60    ICS: Basic Maintenance | 30 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 12000.0
60-126  ,ICS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 30 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -10200.0
126-186 ,ICS: Basic Maintenance | 40 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 9000.0
186-252 ,ICMS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 40 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -7650.0
252-313 ,ICS: Basic Maintenance | 20 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 13500.0
313-379 ,ICS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 20 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -11475.0
379-442 ,ICCMS: Basic Maintenance | 70 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | 12000.0
442-510 ,ICCMS: E-Rate discount (85%) | 70 | 5877 | 0000 | IT0000 | -10200.0
```

The last part doesn't match because there's a missing match to `\s\d{4}\s`. (the 0000 in bold below)

```
ITSM: Laptops, Desktops, Computers | 30 | 4400 | 0000 | IT0000 | 720400.0
```

Comment: Thank you Pranav, that worked splendidly. The lazy match and the duplication of `\d` did make my pattern too complicated. Replacing with `{4}` was helpful.